# What should be done about an answer that is plagiarizing another's post?

Tags: discussion, answers

So in [this answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/37090/1587) if you compare it to the [answer on quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-typical-income-for-a-manga-artist-in-Japan) it linked to [in the comments](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/36456/how-does-a-mangaka-get-paid/37230#comment50233_37090) it's identical minus proper formatting such as the quotes and links from where the quotes come from.

Today it appears the author of the post from quora [posted an answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/37230/1587), because it will be removed as not being an answer here is a screenshot for those who can't see deleted posts

[image: post]

However Golden Time seems to claim it is their post

> This is a comment that i wrote about one moth ago i cant find the link but you can find some good answers in the link that i gave you

[Oct 29 at 20:42](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/36456/how-does-a-mangaka-get-paid/37230#comment50234_37090) (note that they posted this ~12 minutes after posting a link to a page with near identical content)

> Actually its a copy paste from my own comment should i still put the name?

[Oct 30 at 6:17](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/36456/how-does-a-mangaka-get-paid/37230#comment50249_37090)

from my perspective even if the David Sodeyama above isn't *the* David Sodeyama who made the post Golden Time's answer is a poor copy and paste (as it didn't even preserve the link where it says *"According to this article"* so there is no articular to speak of) and they are *"taking someone else's work or ideas and passing them off as one's own."*

So my question is what should be done with this answer?

Comment: I think one way to confirm the user here is the user there is if the user there edits their post saying he's the user here.

Comment: We can't just stop or control plagiarism in cyber world. It's too difficult. Why not we just edit the answer/post and put some credit to the owner? Flag or report it?

Comment: While we can't stop plagiarism for happening, it's irresponsible to allow blatant acts such as this one go by without scrutiny. Straight copy and paste jobs for answers will not be tolerated. Passing off a copied answer from someone is your own is an even worse offense. The user, being unregistered, was given is warning about this behavior in the comments. If the user tries to pull the same shit again, his account will be subject to deletion. While we definitely don't want copypasta answers, we also want to discourage straight quotes of other answer, even with a link back.

Comment: We'd like to encourage users so summarize the key points of passages they quote instead of copying and quoting the entire passage. However people are lazy. If you see and answer that's looks like they just dropped block quote and a link to the source, please try to encourage the answer to summarize the key points of the quote. At little effort can go a long way in making a better answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Plagiarizing entire passage of text without proper attribution is *completely* irresponsible and unacceptable. The least you can do is provide a link to the original.

The first offenses of blatant plagiarism without attribution will merit a warning and deletion of the answer. Subsequent offenses, depending on the frequency and severity may result in possible suspension of the offending account, on top of deletion of the answer. For unregistered users, simple deletion of the answer is enough.

With that being said, even if the original writer, David Sodeyama, is in the right. Soliciting votes and views on another Q&A site within an answer is discouraged. These answers should be deleted, because they are not answers. We are us and they are they, it's fine to cite a passage from their answer on another site, provided you properly attribute it. But don't go about asking users to go to another site, register, and vote on your answer.

In this case it should be noted that Quora's [terms of use](https://www.quora.com/How-can-material-on-Quora-be-reused-elsewhere-What-are-the-licensing-terms-What-about-in-the-case-where-a-user-has-selected-the-not-for-reproduction-option) allow for reproduction on external sites, unless the material is explicitly designated "[not for reproduction](https://www.quora.com/How-does-Quora-intend-to-make-the-not-for-reproduction-feature-enforceable)"

> Subject to these Terms, Quora gives you a worldwide, royalty-free, non-assignable and non-exclusive license to re-post any of the Content on Quora anywhere on the rest of the web provided that the Content was added to the Service after April 22, 2010, and provided that the user who created the content has not explicitly marked the content as not for reproduction, and provided that you: (a) do not modify the Content; (b) attribute Quora with a human and machine-followable link (an A tag) linking back to the page displaying the original source of the content on quora.com; (c) upon request, either by Quora or a user, remove the user's name from Content which the user has subsequently made anonymous; (d) upon request, either by Quora or by a user who contributed to the Content, make a reasonable effort to update a particular piece of Content to the latest version on quora.com; and (e) upon request, either by Quora or by a user who contributed to the Content, make a reasonable attempt to delete Content that has been deleted on quora.com.

Per Quora's Terms of Use, the author's expressed permission is not required in this case, but proper attribution is required.

All in all, it's been made clear that the user in question did not personally write the answer. It should be noted that subsequent plagiarism attempts in the future by this (currently unregistered) user will result in the destruction of his user account, without any further warnings.

Comment: This user and other users in the future.